# How can I make an exe run in HTML or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I've heard a lot of things about that posing too much of a security threat, but this site will only be run on the computer its saved on.
I've tried `<a href= "/app.exe">`, but only in IE will it ask if you want to run it.

Comment: IE is able to do so because of a long story and a war with Netscape, but then, if things are different nowadays there's a reason. If you want to run some program on the client, you may want to completely rethink your approach.

Comment: @MaxArt What if it's a web-based GUI for a local set of programs? In such a case it would probably be acceptable for a link to run a program. That said, I'd have a server running to serve the pages and run the programs, much more reliable.

Comment: I guess you could use a custom protocol that runs the linked .exe .. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Kolink That's exactly the point. You have a web-based GUI? Keep it like it. You want to run an application? Then make an application. Mixing thing usually ends up in ugly results, not to mention security issues.